# history.push with Logout Icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, logout

I am using a material ui icon as a logout button. I am using it like this:

```
function logout(props:any){
  localStorage.removeItem("token");
  return(
    <Redirect to="/login" />
  )
  //props.history.push("/login");
}

 <ExitToAppIcon onClick={logout}></ExitToAppIcon>
```

When I click the icon, token is removed from the localStorage but it doesn't redirect to the `/login`page and if I use the line `props.history.push("/login");`instead of `Redirect`, the page crashes and gives me this error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.history.push')

App.tsx:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component= {HomePage}></Route>
      <Route path='/login' component= {LoginPage}></Route>
      <PrivateRoute
      path='/panel'
      isAuthenticated={token}
      component={PanelHomePage}
      />
      <Redirect from='*' to='/404' />
      </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I fix the redirection issue?

Comment: `history` prop only exists in the components that are direct descendants of `Route` components (in your case `HomePage`, `LoginPage`, and `PanelHomePage`). Are you calling the `push` method there?

Comment: @Kox The Icon is inside a Drawer is a component that I am calling on ```PanelHomePage```. The ```push```is being called on the drawer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a try using [`useHistory`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook, from the documentation:

> The `useHistory` hook gives you access to the history instance that you may use to navigate.

Like the following:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const YourComponent = () => {
   let history = useHistory();

   const logout = () => {
      localStorage.removeItem('token');

      history.push('/login');
   }

   /* rest of your component code */

   return (
       { /* your other elements */ }
       <ExitToAppIcon onClick={logout}></ExitToAppIcon>
   )
}
```

I hope this helps!